# Can webots start without windows?

Tags: webots

I want to use the web interface of webots (--stream) instead of using the desktop application,How do you do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208419/does-webots-have-headless-mode#58213519

Comment: See also this post: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24174/headless-mode-with-gpus